# Using let in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I want to write a program to find the roots of the quadratic equation in Scheme. I used LET for certain bindings.

```lisp
(define roots-with-let
  (λ (a b c)
    (let ((4ac (* 4 a c))
          (2a (* 2 a))
          (discriminant (sqrt ( - (* b b) (4ac)))))
      (cons ( / ( + (- b) discriminant) 2a)
            ( / ( - (- b) discriminant) 2a)))))
```

I defined the discriminant with `4ac`  since I did not want `(* 4 a c)`. Even though I have defined `(4ac (* 4 a c))`,  it is giving me this error:

> expand: unbound identifier in module in: `4ac`.

My question is how is let evaluated (what order)? And if i want `4ac` in my `let` should i write another inner `let`? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This is an example from SICP Lecture/Book !

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use `let*` instead of `let`.

The difference between `let` and `let*` is the following:

`let*` binds variables from left to right. Earlier bindings can be used in new binding further to the right (or down).

`let` on the other hand can be thought of as syntactic sugar (or macro) for simple lambda abstraction:

```
(let ((a exp1)
      (b exp2))
   exp)
```

is equivalent to

```
((lambda (a b)
    exp)
 exp1 exp2)
```

Comment: Could you please comment on the difference of the  evaluation order between the two?

Comment: it's not (only) about evaluation order, it's mostly about scope.  in the plain let, the scope of every variable is only the expression, not the bindings.  in let*, the scope of each variable is the expression and every binding after itself.

Answer (score 8):

- 4ac is a variable with a numeric value, so (4ac) is not meaningful.
- LET binds all variables, but the variables can't be used in the computations for the values.

This does not work:

```
(let ((a 1) (b 1) (c (* a b)))
   c)
```

Use:

```
(let ((a 1) (b 1))
  (let ((c (* a b)))
    c))
```

Above introduces A and B with the first LET. In the second LET both A and B now can be used to compute C.

Or:

```
(let* ((a 1) (b 1) (c (* a b)))
   c)
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a [special `let`-construct](http://www.cs.vassar.edu/~cs295/handouts/let-forms.pdf) (`let*`) here since the variables inside the let-definition refer to each other.

It's rather a problem of defining a scope than of evaluating an expression (In usual `let`-definitions, the order of evaluation doesn't matter since the values may not use each other)

Answer (score 2):

When you use let, the bindings are not visible in any of the bodies. Use let* instead and see the RNRS docs for details.