# How does the yin-yang puzzle work?

Tags: scheme, callcc

I'm trying to grasp the semantics of call/cc in Scheme, and the Wikipedia page on continuations shows the yin-yang puzzle as an example:

```
(let* ((yin
         ((lambda (cc) (display #\@) cc) (call-with-current-continuation (lambda (c) c))))
       (yang
         ((lambda (cc) (display #\*) cc) (call-with-current-continuation (lambda (c) c)))) )
    (yin yang))
```

It should output `@*@**@***@****@...`, 
but I don't understand why; I'd expect it to output `@*@*********`...

Can somebody explain in detail why the yin-yang puzzle works the way it works?

Comment: STk output this:
`@*@**@***@****@*****@******@*******@********@*********@**********@***********`

Comment: How would a solution look like that makes the continuation explicit, as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827620/call-cc-in-lua-possible ?

Comment: Any paper references where the yin-yang puzzle is first shown?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think I understand this one fully, but I can only think of one (*extremely* hand-wavy) explanation for this:

- The first @ and * are printed when `yin` and `yang` are first bound in the `let*`. `(yin yang)` is applied, and it goes back to the top, right after the first call/cc is finished.
- The next @ and * are printed, then another * is printed because this time through, `yin` is re-bound to the value of the second call/cc.
- `(yin yang)` is applied again, but this time **it's executing in the original `yang`'s environment**, where `yin` is bound to the first call/cc, so control goes back to printing another @. The `yang` argument contains the continuation that was re-captured on the second pass through, which as we've already seen, will result in printing `**`. So on this third pass, `@*` will be printed, then this double-star-printing continuation gets invoked, so it ends up with 3 stars, and then this triple-star continuation is re-captured, ...

Comment: Thanks! Seems I get the idea now.
The problem was in the way I understood let* semantics. 
For example, (let* ((a #\a)(b #\b)) b)
I though it worked in the following way:
create new environment -> evaluate #\a -> bind #\a to a -> evaluate #\b -> bind #\b to b.
It seems it actually works in the following way:
evaluate #\a -> create new environment -> bind #\a to a -> evaluate #\b -> create new environment -> bind #\b to b.
That way environments in initial yin and yang continuations are different. Am I right?

Comment: When I first tried to work out the evaluation steps for this, I ended up with `@***********` as well. But rethinking this, when call/cc causes re-execution of the "binding" step in a `let`, it doesn't overwrite the original binding that may be captured in a closure elsewhere (in this case, the closure is the continuation captured in the yang expression). So I think the error in thinking it prints `@*********` is trying to treat re-binding in `let` the same as a `set!`.

Answer (score 22):

#### Understanding Scheme

I think at least half of the problem with understanding this puzzle is the Scheme syntax, which most are not familiar with.

First of all, I personally find the `call/cc x` to be harder to comprehend than the equivalent alternative, `x get/cc`. It still *calls x, passing it the current continuation*, but somehow is more amenable to being represented in my brain circuitry.

With that in mind, the construct `(call-with-current-continuation (lambda (c) c))` becomes simply `get-cc`. We’re now down to this:

```
(let* ((yin
         ((lambda (cc) (display #\@) cc) get-cc))
       (yang
         ((lambda (cc) (display #\*) cc) get-cc)) )
    (yin yang))
```

The next step is the body of the inner lambda. `(display #\@) cc`, in the more familiar syntax (to me, anyway) means `print @; return cc;`. While we’re at it, let’s also rewrite `lambda (cc) body` as `function (arg) { body }`, remove a bunch of parentheses, and change function calls to the C-like syntax, to get this:

```javascript
(let*  yin =
         (function(arg) { print @; return arg; })(get-cc)
       yang =
         (function(arg) { print *; return arg; })(get-cc)
    yin(yang))
```

It’s starting to make more sense now. It’s now a small step to rewrite this completely into C-like syntax (or JavaScript-like, if you prefer), to get this:

```javascript
var yin, yang;
yin = (function(arg) { print @; return arg; })(get-cc);
yang = (function(arg) { print *; return arg; })(get-cc);
yin(yang);
```

The hardest part is now over, we’ve decoded this from Scheme! Just kidding; it was only hard because I had no previous experience with Scheme. So, let’s get to figuring out how this actually works.

#### A primer on continuations

Observe the strangely formulated core of yin and yang: it defines a function *and then immediately calls it*. It looks just like `(function(a,b) { return a+b; })(2, 3)`, which can be simplified to `5`. But simplifying the calls inside yin/yang would be a mistake, because we’re not passing it an ordinary value. We’re passing the function a *continuation*.

A continuation is a strange beast at first sight. Consider the much simpler program:

```javascript
var x = get-cc;
print x;
x(5);
```

Initially `x` is set to the current continuation object (bear with me), and `print x` gets executed, printing something like `<ContinuationObject>`. So far so good.

But a continuation is like a function; it can be called with one argument. What it does is: take the argument, and then **jump** to wherever that continuation was created, restoring all context, and making it so that `get-cc` returns this argument.

In our example, the argument is `5`, so we essentially jump right back into the middle of that `var x = get-cc` statement, only this time `get-cc` returns `5`. So `x` becomes `5`, and the next statement goes on to print 5. After that we try to call `5(5)`, which is a type error, and the program crashes.

Observe that calling the continuation is a **jump**, not a call. It never returns back to where the continuation was called. That’s important.

#### How the program works

If you followed that, then don’t get your hopes up: this part is really the hardest. Here’s our program again, dropping the variable declarations because this is pseudo-code anyway:

```javascript
yin = (function(arg) { print @; return arg; })(get-cc);
yang = (function(arg) { print *; return arg; })(get-cc);
yin(yang);
```

The first time line 1 and 2 are hit, they are simple now: get the continuation, call the function(arg), print `@`, return, store that continuation in `yin`. Same with `yang`. We’ve now printed `@*`.

Next, we call the continuation in `yin`, passing it `yang`. This makes us jump to line 1, right inside that get-cc, and make it return `yang` instead. The value of `yang` is now passed into the function, which prints `@`, and then returns the value of `yang`. Now `yin` is assigned that continuation that `yang` has. Next we just proceed to line 2: get c/c, print `*`, store the c/c in `yang`. We now have `@*@*`. And lastly, we go to line 3.

Remember that `yin` now has the continuation from when line 2 was first executed. So we jump to line 2, printing a second `*` and updating `yang`. We now have `@*@**`. Lastly, call the `yin` continuation again, which will jump to line 1, printing a `@`. And so on. Frankly, at this point my brain throws an OutOfMemory exception and I lose track of everything. But at least we got to `@*@**`!

This is hard to follow and even harder to explain, obviously. The perfect way to do this would be to step through it in a debugger which can represent continuations, but alas, I don’t know of any. I hope you have enjoyed this; I certainly have.

Comment: I got a javascript code snippet of yinyang puzzle, and I follow the code carefully and I got to the same step with you.
But I finally find that it has to be in Scheme for me to fully understand it.
I've written my answer below.

Comment: You can further simplify the IIFE as something like `yin = get-cc; print @`.

Answer (score 8):

YinYang puzzle is written in Scheme. I assume you know the basic syntax of Scheme.

But I assume you don't know `let*` or `call-with-current-continuation`, I will  explain these two keywords.

### Explain `let*`

If you already know that, you can skip to `Explain call-with-current-continuation`

`let*`, which looks like `let`, acts like `let`, but will evaluate its defined variables(the `(yin ...)` and `(yang ...)`) one by one and eagerly. That means, it will first evaluate `yin`, and than `yang`.

You can read more in here:
[Using Let in Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946050/using-let-in-scheme)

### Explain `call-with-current-continuation`

If you already know that, you can skip to `Yin-Yang puzzle`.

It's a little bit hard to explain `call-with-current-continuation`. So I will use a metaphor to explain it.

Image a wizard who knew a spell, which was `call-with-current-continuation`. Once he cast the spell, he would create a new universe, and send him-self to it. But he could **do nothing** in the new universe but waiting for someone calling his name. Once **been called**, the wizard would return to the original universe, having the poor guy -- 'someone' -- in hand, and go on his wizard life. If not been called, when the new universe ended, the wizard also returned to the original universe.

Ok, let's be more technical.

`call-with-current-continuation` is a function which accept a function as parameter. Once you call `call-with-current-continuation` with a function `F`, it will pack the current running environment, which is called `current-continuation`, as a parameter `C`, and send it to function `F`, and execute `F`. So the whole program becomes `(F C)`. Or being more JavaScript: `F(C);`. `C` acts like a function. If `C` is not called in `F`, then it is an ordinary program, when `F` returns, `call-with-current-continuation` has a value as `F`'s return value. But if `C` is called with a parameter `V`, it will change the whole program again. The program changes back to a **state** when `call-with-current-continuation` been called. But now `call-with-current-continuation` yields a value, which is `V`. And the program continues.

Let's take an example.

```
(define (f return)
  (return 2)
  3)
(display (f whatever)) ;; 3
(display (call-with-current-continuation f)) ;; 2
(display (call-with-current-continuation (lambda (x) 4))) ;; 4
```

The first `display` output `3`, of cause.

But the second `display` output `2`. Why?

Let's dive into it.

When evaluating `(display (call-with-current-continuation f))`, it will first evaluate `(call-with-current-continuation f)`. We know that it will change the whole program to

```
(f C)
```

Considering the definition for `f`, it has a `(return 2)`. We must evaluate `(C 2)`. That's when the `continuation` being called. So it change the whole program back to

```
(display (call-with-current-continuation f))
```

But now, `call-with-current-continuation` has value `2`. So the program becomes:

```
(display 2)
```

### Yin-Yang puzzle

Let's look at the puzzle.

```
(let* ((yin
         ((lambda (cc) (display #\@) cc) (call-with-current-continuation (lambda (c) c))))
       (yang
         ((lambda (cc) (display #\*) cc) (call-with-current-continuation (lambda (c) c)))))
      (yin yang))
```

Let's make it more readable.

```
(define (id c) c)
(define (f cc) (display #\@) cc)
(define (g cc) (display #\*) cc)
(let* ((yin
         (f (call-with-current-continuation id)))
       (yang
         (g (call-with-current-continuation id))))
      (yin yang))
```

Let's run the program in our brain.

#### Round 0

`let*` make us to evaluate `yin` first. `yin` is

```
(f (call-with-current-continuation id))
```

So we evaluate `(call-with-current-continuation id)` first. It packs the current environment, which we call it `C_0` to distinguish with other continuation in the time-line, and it enters a whole new universe: `id`. But `id` just returns `C_0`.

We should Remember what `C_0` is. `C_0` is a program like this:

```
(let* ((yin
         (f ###))
       (yang
         (g (call-with-current-continuation id))))
      (yin yang))
```

`###` is a placeholder, which in the future will be filled by the value that `C_0` takes back.

But `id` just returns `C_0`. It doesn't call `C_0`. If it calls, we will enter `C_0`'s universe. But it didn't, so we continue to evaluate `yin`.

```
(f C_0) ;; yields C_0
```

`f` is a function like `id`, but it has a side effect -- outputting `@`.

So the program output `@` and let `yin` to be `C_0`. Now the program becomes

```
(let* ((yin C_0)
       (yang
         (g (call-with-current-continuation id))))
      (yin yang))
```

After `yin` evaluated, we start to evaluate `yang`. `yang` is

```
(g (call-with-current-continuation id))
```

`call-with-current-continuation` here create another continuation, named `C_1`. `C_1` is:

```
(let* ((yin C_0)
       (yang
         (g ###)))
      (yin yang))
```

`###` is placeholder. Note that in this continuation, `yin`'s value is determined (that's what `let*` do). We are sure that `yin`'s value is `C_0` here.

Since `(id C_1)` is `C_1`, so `yang`'s value is

```
(g C_1)
```

`g` has a side effect -- outputting `*`. So the program does.

`yang`'s value is now `C_1`.

By now, we have displayed `@*`

So now it becomes:

```
(let* ((yin C_0)
       (yang C_1))
      (yin yang))
```

As both `yin` and `yang` are solved, we should evaluate `(yin yang)`. It's

```
(C_0 C_1)
```

Holy SH*T!

But finally, `C_0` is called. So we fly into the `C_0` universe and forget all about these sh*ts. We will never go back to this universe again.

#### Round 1

`C_0` take with `C_1` back. The program now becomes(If you forget what `C_0` stands for, go back to see it):

```
(let* ((yin
         (f C_1))
       (yang
         (g (call-with-current-continuation id))))
      (yin yang))
```

Ah, we find that `yin`'s value is not determined yet. So we evaluate it. In the process of evaluating `yin`, we output an `@` as `f`'s side effect. And we know `yin` is `C_1` now.

We begin to evaluate `yang`, we came across `call-with-current-continuation` again. We are practiced. We create a continuation `C_2` which stands for:

```
(let* ((yin C_1)
       (yang
         (g ###)))
      (yin yang))
```

And we display a `*` as `g` executing. And we come here

```
(let* ((yin C_1)
       (yang C_2))
      (yin yang))
```

So we got:

```
(C_1 C_2)
```

You know where we are going. We are going to `C_1`'s universe. We recall it from memory(or copy and paste from webpage). It is now:

```
(let* ((yin C_0)
       (yang
         (g C_2)))
      (yin yang))
```

We know in `C_1`'s universe, `yin`'s value has been determined. So we begin to evaluate `yang`. As we are practiced, I will directly tell you that it displays `*` and becomes:

```
(C_0 C_2)
```

Now we have printed `@*@**`, and we are going to `C_0`'s universe taking with `C_2`.

#### Round 2

As we are practiced, I will tell you that we display '@', `yin` is `C_2`, and  we create a new continuation `C_3`, which stands for:

```
(let* ((yin C_2)
       (yang
         (g ###)))
      (yin yang))
```

And we display `*`, `yang` is `C_3`, and it becomes

```
(C_2 C_3)
```

And we can continue. But I will stop here, I have showed you what Yin-Yang puzzle's first several outputs are.

### Why the number of `*` increases?

Now your head is full of details. I will make a summary for you.

I will use a Haskell like syntax to simplify. And `cc` is short for `call-with-current-continuation`.

When `#C_i#` is bracketed by `#`, it means the continuation is create here. `;` means output

---

```
yin = f cc id
yang = g cc id
yin yang

---

yin = f #C_0# ; @
yang = g cc id
yin yang

---

yin = C_0
yang = g #C_1# ; *
yin yang

---

C_0 C_1

---

yin = f C_1 ; @
yang = g #C_2# ; *
yin yang

---

C_1 C_2

---

yin = C_0
yang = g C_2 ; *
yin yang

---

C_0 C_2

---

yin = f C_2 ; @
yang = g #C_3#; *
yin yang

---

C_2 C_3

---

yin = C_1
yang = g C_3 ; *
yin yang

---

C_1 C_3

---

yin = C_0
yang = g C_3 ; *
yin yang

---

C_0 C_3
```

If you observe carefully, it will be obvious to you that

1. There are lots of universes(in fact infinite), but `C_0` is the only universe that started by `f`. Others is started by `g`.
2. `C_0 C_n` always makes a new continuation `C_max`. It's because `C_0` is the first universe which `g cc id` has **not** been executed.
3. `C_0 C_n` also display `@`. `C_n C_m` which n is not 0 will display `*`.
4. Time by time the program is deduced to `C_0 C_n`, and I will prove that `C_0 C_n` is separated by more and more other expression, which leads to `@*@**@***...`

### A little bit math

Assume [image: C_n] (n != 0) is the biggest numbered in all continuations, and then `C_0 C_n` is called.

**Assumption: When `C_0 C_n` is called, `C_n` is the current maximum numbered continuation.**

Now [image: C_{n+1}] is created by `C_0 C_n` like this:

```
yin = f C_n ; @
yang = g #C_{n+1}#
yin yang
```

So we conclude that:

**Theorem I. If `C_0 C_n` is called, It will produce a continuation [image: C_{n+1}], in which `yin` is `C_n`**.

Then next step is `C_n C_{n+1}`.

```
yin = C_{n-1}
yang = g C_{n+1} ; *
yin yang
```

The reason why `yin` is `C_{n-1}` is that When `C_n` being created it obeyed **Theorem I**.

And then `C_{n-1} C_{n+1}` is called, and we know when `C_{n-1}` is created, it also obeyed **Theorem I**. So We have `C_{n-2} C_{n+1}`.

`C_{n+1}` is the in-variation. So we have the second theorem:

**Theorem II. If `C_n C_m` which `n < m` and `n > 0` is called, It will become `C_{n-1} C_m`.**

And we have Manually checked `C_0` `C_1` `C_2` `C_3`. They obey the Assumption and all Theorems. And we know how first `@` and `*` is created.

So we can write patterns below.

```
C_0 C_1 ; @ *
C_[1-0] C_2 ; @ * *
C_[2-0] C_3 ; @ * * *
...
```

It not so strict, but I'd like to write:

Q.E.D.

Comment: Wow ! Great answer. SO members need more contributions from You. Thank You for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 6):

*Musings first, possible answer at the end.*

I think the code can be re-written like this:

```
; call (yin yang)
(define (yy yin yang) (yin yang))

; run (call-yy) to set it off
(define (call-yy)
    (yy
        ( (lambda (cc) (display #\@) cc) (call/cc (lambda (c) c)) )
        ( (lambda (cc) (display #\*) cc) (call/cc (lambda (c) c)) )
     )
)
```

Or with some extra display statements to help see what is happening:

```
; create current continuation and tell us when you do
(define (ccc)
    (display "call/cc=")
    (call-with-current-continuation (lambda (c) (display c) (newline) c))
)

; call (yin yang)
(define (yy yin yang) (yin yang))

; run (call-yy) to set it off
(define (call-yy)
    (yy
        ( (lambda (cc) (display "yin : ") (display #\@) (display cc) (newline) cc) 
            (ccc) )
        ( (lambda (cc) (display "yang : ") (display #\*) (display cc) (newline) cc) 
            (ccc) )
     )
)
```

Or like this:

```
(define (ccc2) (call/cc (lambda (c) c)) )
(define (call-yy2)
    (
        ( (lambda (cc) (display #\@) cc) (ccc2) )
        ( (lambda (cc) (display #\*) cc) (ccc2) )
    )
)
```

**Possible Answer**

*This may not be right, but I'll have a go.*

I think the key point is that a 'called' continuation returns the stack to some previous state - as if nothing else had happened. Of course it doesn't know that we monitoring it by displaying `@` and `*` characters.

We initially define `yin` to be a continuation `A` that will do this:

```
1. restore the stack to some previous point
2. display @
3. assign a continuation to yin
4. compute a continuation X, display * and assign X to yang
5. evaluate yin with the continuation value of yang - (yin yang)
```

But if we call a `yang` continuation, this happens:

```
1. restore the stack to some point where yin was defined
2. display *
3. assign a continuation to yang
4. evaluate yin with the continuation value of yang - (yin yang)
```

**We start here.**

First time through you get `yin=A` and `yang=B` as `yin` and `yang` are being initialised.

```
The output is @*
```

(Both `A` and `B` continuations are computed.)

Now `(yin yang)` is evaluated as `(A B)` for the first time.

We know what `A` does. It does this:

```
1. restores the stack - back to the point where yin and yang were being initialised.
2. display @
3. assign a continuation to yin - this time, it is B, we don't compute it.
4. compute another continuation B', display * and assign B' to yang

The output is now @*@*

5. evaluate yin (B) with the continuation value of yang (B')
```

Now `(yin yang)` is evaluated as `(B B')`.

We know what `B` does. It does this:

```
1. restore the stack - back to the point where yin was already initialised.
2. display *
3. assign a continuation to yang - this time, it is B'

The output is now @*@**

4. evaluate yin with the continuation value of yang (B')
```

Since the stack was restored to the point where `yin=A`, `(yin yang)` is evaluated as `(A B')`.

We know what `A` does. It does this:

```
1. restores the stack - back to the point where yin and yang were being initialised.
2. display @
3. assign a continuation to yin - this time, it is B', we don't compute it.
4. compute another continuation B", display * and assign B" to yang

The output is now @*@**@*

5. evaluate yin (B') with the continuation value of yang (B")
```

We know what `B'` does. It does this:

```
1. restore the stack - back to the point where yin=B.
2. display *
3. assign a continuation to yang - this time, it is B"

The output is now @*@**@**

4. evaluate yin (B) with the continuation value of yang (B")
```

Now `(yin yang)` is evaluated as `(B B")`.

We know what `B` does. It does this:

```
1. restore the stack - back to the point where yin=A and yang were being initialised.
2. display *
3. assign a continuation to yang - this time, it is B'"

The output is now @*@**@***

4. evaluate yin with the continuation value of yang (B'")
```

Since the stack was restored to the point where `yin=A`, `(yin yang)` is evaluated as `(A B'")`.

.......

I think we have a pattern now.

Each time we call `(yin yang)` we loop through a stack of `B` continuations until we get back to when `yin=A` and we display `@`. The we loop through the stack of `B` continuations writing a `*` each time.

(I'd be really happy if this is roughly right!)

Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 1):

As another answer said, we first simplify `(call-with-current-continuation (lambda (c) c))` with `get-cc`.

```
(let* ((yin
         ((lambda (cc) (display #\@) cc) get-cc))
       (yang
         ((lambda (cc) (display #\*) cc) get-cc)) )
    (yin yang))
```

Now, the two lambda are just a identical function associated with side-effects. Let's call those functions `f` (for `display #\@`) and `g` (for `display #\*`).

```
(let* ((yin (f get-cc))
       (yang (g get-cc)))
    (yin yang))
```

Next we need to work out the evaluation order. To be clear, I will introduce a "step expression" which makes every evaluation step explicit. First let's ask: what is the above function requires?

It requires definitions of `f` and `g`. In step expression, we write

```
s0 f g =>
```

The first step is to calculate `yin`, but that require evaluate of `(f get-cc)`, and the later require `get-cc`.

Roughly speaking, `get-cc` gives you a value that represents the "current continuation". Let's say this is `s1` since this is the next step. So we write

```
s0 f g => s1 f g ?
s1 f g cc =>
```

Note that the parameters are scopeless, which means the `f` and `g` in `s0` and `s1` are not necessary the same and they are only to be used within the current step. This makes the context information explicit. Now, what is the value for `cc`? Since it is "current continuation", it is kind of the same `s1` with `f` and `g` bound to the same value.

```
s0 f g => s1 f g (s1 f g)
s1 f g cc =>
```

Once we have `cc`, we can evaluate `f get-cc`. Also, since `f` is not used in the following code, we don't have to pass on this value.

```
s0 f g => s1 f g (s1 f g)
s1 f g cc => s2 g (f cc)
s2 g yin =>
```

The next is the similar for `yang`. But now we have one more value to pass on: `yin`.

```
s0 f g => s1 f g (s1 f g)
s1 f g cc => s2 g (f cc)
s2 g yin => s3 g yin (s3 g yin)
s3 g yin cc => s4 yin (g cc)
s4 yin yang =>
```

Finally, the last step is to apply `yang` to `yin`.

```
s0 f g => s1 f g (s1 f g)
s1 f g cc => s2 g (f cc)
s2 g yin => s3 g yin (s3 g yin)
s3 g yin cc => s4 yin (g cc)
s4 yin yang => yin yang
```

This finished the construct of step expression. Translate it back to Scheme is simple:

```
(let* ([s4 (lambda (yin yang) (yin yang))]
       [s3 (lambda (yin cc) (s4 yin (g cc))]
       [s2 (lambda (yin) (s3 yin ((lambda (cc) (s3 yin cc))))]
       [s1 (lambda (cc) (s2 (f cc)))])
      (s1 s1))
```

The detailed evaluation order (here the lambda inside the body of `s2` was simply expressed as partial evaluation `s3 yin` rather than `(lambda (cc) (s3 yin cc))`):

```
(s1 s1)
=> (s2 (f s1))
=> @|(s2 s1)
=> @|(s3 s1 (s3 s1))
=> @|(s4 s1 (g (s3 s1)))
=> @*|(s4 s1 (s3 s1))
=> @*|(s1 (s3 s1))
=> @*|(s2 (f (s3 s1)))
=> @*@|(s2 (s3 s1))
=> @*@|(s2 (s3 s1))
=> @*@|(s3 (s3 s1) (s3 (s3 s1)))
=> @*@|(s4 (s3 s1) (g (s3 (s3 s1))))
=> @*@*|(s4 (s3 s1) (s3 (s3 s1)))
=> @*@*|(s3 s1 (s3 (s3 s1)))
=> @*@*|(s4 s1 (g (s3 (s3 s1))))
=> @*@**|(s4 s1 (s3 (s3 s1)))
=> @*@**|(s1 (s3 (s3 s1)))
=> ...
```

(Remember, when evaluating `s2` or `s4`, the parameter is going to be evaluated first

Answer (score 1):

This an old puzzle from the master of obfuscation David Madore, who
created Unlambda. The puzzle has been discussed comp.lang.scheme several
times.

A nice solution from Taylor Campbell:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.scheme/pUedvrKYY5w/uIjTc_T1LOEJ

The original post from David Madore (1999):
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.scheme/Fysq_Wplxsw/awxEZ_uxW20J

Answer (score 0):

I do not know yet with my heart, but I can deduce it with pencil and paper in the Unlambda variant.

The Unlambda variant of the ying-yang puzzle is:

```
``r`ci`.*`ci
```

and its run result is:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
...
```

(see it among the Wikipedia page [call/cc: examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation#Examples).)

I have deduced how this is coming out, I am showing the tree rewritings and the continution repluggings in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\parens}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}
\DeclareMathOperator{\callcc}{c}
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{i}
\DeclareMathOperator{\brk}{r}
\DeclareMathOperator{\prnt}{.\!\!*}
\newcommand{\cont}{\mathop{\mathit{cont}}}
\newcommand{\yingyang}{\ying\parens{yang}}
\newcommand{\ying}{\brk  \parens{\cc}}
\newcommand{\yang}{\prnt \parens{\cc}}
\newcommand{\currc}{\callcc \id}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{c|c|c}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1cm,
            level 1/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
            level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm},
            level 3/.style={sibling distance=0.5cm}]
            \node {yingyang}
            child {node {ying}
                child {node {$\brk$}}
                child {node {currc}
                    child {node {$\callcc$}}
                    child {node {$\id$}}
                }
            }
            child {node {yang}
                child {node {$\prnt$}}
                child {node {currc}
                    child {node {$\callcc$}}
                    child {node {$\id$}}
                }
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
        &
        \begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1cm,
            level 1/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
            level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm},
            level 3/.style={sibling distance=0.5cm}]
            \node {yingyang}
            child {node {ying}
                child {node {$\brk$}}
                child {node {\bf 1:\boxed{\callcc \Leftarrow \id}}
                    child {node {$\callcc$}}
                    child {node {$\id$}}
                }
            }
            child {node {yang}
                child {node {$\prnt$}}
                child {node {currc}
                    child {node {$\callcc$}}
                    child {node {$\id$}}
                }
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
        &
        \begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1cm,
            level 1/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
            level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm},
            level 3/.style={sibling distance=0.5cm}]
            \node {$\brk \parens{\id \cont_1} \operatorname{yang}$}
            child {node {$\brk \parens{\id \cont_1}$}
                child {node {$\brk$}}
                child {node {$\id \cont_1$}
                    child {node {$\id$}}
                    child {node {$\cont_1$}}
                }
            }
            child {node {yang}
                child {node {$\prnt$}}
                child {node {currc}
                    child {node {$\callcc$}}
                    child {node {$\id$}}
                }
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \\\hline
        \begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1cm,
            level 1/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
            level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm},
            level 3/.style={sibling distance=0.5cm}]
            \node {$\brk \cont_1 \operatorname{yang}$}
            child {node {$\brk \cont_1$}
                child {node {$\brk$}}
                child {node {$\cont_1$}}
            }
            child {node {yang}
                child {node {$\prnt$}}
                child {node {currc}
                    child {node {$\callcc$}}
                    child {node {$\id$}}
                }
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
        &
        \begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1cm,
            level 1/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
            level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm},
            level 3/.style={sibling distance=0.5cm}]
            \node {$\cont_1 \operatorname{yang}$}
            child {node {$\cont_1$}}
            child {node {yang}
                child {node {$\prnt$}}
                child {node {currc}
                    child {node {$\callcc$}}
                    child {node {$\id$}}
                }
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
        &
        \begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1cm,
            level 1/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
            level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm},
            level 3/.style={sibling distance=0.5cm}]
            \node {$\cont_1 \operatorname{yang}$}
            child {node {$\cont_1$}}
            child {node {yang}
                child {node {$\prnt$}}
                child {node {\bf 2:\boxed{\callcc \Leftarrow \id}}
                    child {node {$\callcc$}}
                    child {node {$\id$}}
                }
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \\\hline
        \begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1cm,
            level 1/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
            level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm},
            level 3/.style={sibling distance=0.5cm}]
            \node {$\cont_1 \parens{\prnt \parens{\id \cont_2}}$}
            child {node {$\cont_1$}}
            child {node {$\prnt \parens{\id \cont_2}$}
                child {node {$\prnt$}}
                child {node {$\id \cont_2$}
                    child {node {$\id$}}
                    child {node {$\cont_2$}}
                }
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
        &
        \begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1cm,
            level 1/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
            level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm},
            level 3/.style={sibling distance=0.5cm}]
            \node {$\cont_1 \parens{\prnt \cont_2}$}
            child {node {$\cont_1$}}
            child {node {$\prnt \cont_2$}
                child {node {$\prnt$}}
                child {node {$\cont_2$}}
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
        &
        \begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1cm,
            level 1/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
            level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm},
            level 3/.style={sibling distance=0.5cm}]
            \node {$\cont_1 \cont_2$}
            child {node {$\cont_1$}}
            child {node {$\cont_2$}
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \\\hline
        \begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1cm,
            level 1/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
            level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm},
            level 3/.style={sibling distance=0.5cm}]
            \node {$\brk \cont_2 \operatorname{yang}$}
            child {node {$\brk \cont_2$}
                child {node {$\brk$}}
                child {node {$\cont_2$}}
            }
            child {node {yang}
                child {node {$\prnt$}}
                child {node {currc}
                    child {node {$\callcc$}}
                    child {node {$\id$}}
                }
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
        &
        \begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1cm,
            level 1/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
            level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm},
            level 3/.style={sibling distance=0.5cm}]
            \node {$\cont_2 \operatorname{yang}$}
            child {node {$\cont_2$}}
            child {node {yang}
                child {node {$\prnt$}}
                child {node {currc}
                    child {node {$\callcc$}}
                    child {node {$\id$}}
                }
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
        &
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```