# call/cc in Lua - Possible?

Tags: lua, continuations, callcc

The Wikipedia article on [Continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) says:
"In any language which supports **closures**, it is possible to write programs in continuation passing style and **manually implement call/cc**."
Either that is true and I need to know how to do it or it is not true and that statement needs to be corrected.
If this is true, please show me how to implement call/cc in Lua because I can't see how.
I think I'd be able to implement call/cc manually if Lua had the coroutine.clone function as explained [here](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2006-01/msg00652.html).
If closures are not enough to implement call/cc then what else is needed?

**The text below is optional reading.**
*P.S.: Lua has one-shot continuations with its coroutine table. A coroutine.clone function would allow me to clone it to call it multiple times, thus effectively making call/cc possible (unless I misunderstand call/cc). However that cloning function doesn't exist in Lua. Someone on the Lua IRC channel suggested that I use the Pluto library (it implements serialization) to marshal a coroutine, copy it and then unmarshal it and use it again. While that would probably work, I am more interested in the theoretical implementation of call/cc and in finding what is the actual minimum set of features that a language needs to have in order to allow for its manual implementation.*

**EDIT 1:** Ok people, help me out here, this took me a long time because I don't know any Scheme, but I came up with something that should help us out. Please look at the codes below. The first one is a program in Scheme, the second one is the same program but in Lua. 
Hopefully this will help us out. I believe we are **very** close.
P.S.: These examples are taken from the first example on [the Wikipedia article on CallCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation).
**Scheme version**

```
(define call/cc call-with-current-continuation)

; callcc CPS-transformed (thanks to the people from the #scheme channel at freenode.net)
(define cpscallcc
  (lambda (consumer k)
    (let ((cc (lambda (result) (k result))))
      (consumer cc k))))

; this is the continuation we will use to display the "returned" values
(define main-continuation
  (lambda (result)
    (display "--> ")
    (display result)
    (newline)))

; define f function non-CPS
(define (f return)
  (return 2)
  3)

; these are my past attempts at defining a CPS f function
;(define (cps-f return k)
;  (k (return 2)) 3)
;(define (cps-f return k)
;  (k (lambda ()
;       (return 2)
;       3)))

; this is what I came up with - I'm not sure if this is correctly CPS-transformed but I     believe so
(define (cps-f return k)
  (return 2)
  (k 3))

; call the non-CPS f function
(display (f (lambda (x) x))) ; displays 3
(newline)

; call the non-CPS f function with call/cc (I don't understand what this does)
(display (call/cc f)) ; displays 2
(newline)

; now call the CPS version of the f function
(cps-f (lambda (x) x) main-continuation)  ; displays --> 3

; now call the CPS version of the f function with the CPS version of call/cc
(cpscallcc cps-f main-continuation)  ; displays --> 2 but then it also displays --> 3 afterwards -> I'm not sure why it displays the 3 afterwards, as it should only display the 2 just like the non-CPS versions above
```

**Lua version**

```
-- callcc CPS-version
cpscallcc = function(consumer, k)
    local cc = function(result)
        return k(result)  -- ?or k(result)
    end
    return consumer(cc, k)  -- ?or return consumer(cc,k)
end

-- define f function non-CPS
f = function(ret)
    ret(2)
    return 3
end

-- define f function CPS-version (again, not sure this is correct)
cps_f = function(ret, k)
    ret(2)
    k(3)
end

-- call the non-CPS f function
print(f(function(x) return x end))

-- we cant call the non-CPS f function with callcc because
-- Lua doesnt have callcc, but the line below displays the correct expected output (maybe by accident)
--cpscallcc(f, print)

-- now call the CPS version of the f function
cps_f( function(x) return x end, print )  -- displays 3

; now call the CPS version of the f function with the CPS version of call/cc
cpscallcc( cps_f, print) -- displays 2 and then 3 just like the Scheme version!!
-- so apparently the translation from Scheme to Lua is correct...
```

I'm using DrScheme and Lua for Windows - for anyone that wants to help up out those are two easy to download and install tools that just work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two prerequisites to manually implement call/cc per the Wikipedia quote:

1. the language must support closures
2. you must write your program in continuation passing style (CPS)

I suspect you will not like #2.

To write your program in continuation passing style:

1. Every function must take a continuation argument
2. Functions must return by calling their continuation

So, using `k` as the name of the continuation argument, a function would look like:

```
function multiplyadd(k, x, y, z) return k(x * y + z) end
```

The toplevel might use `print` as its continuation, so invoking `multiplyadd` at top level would look like:

```
multiplyadd(print, 2, 4, 1)
```

With that scaffolding we could define call/cc as

```
function callcc(k,f) return f(k,k) end
```

Note that the above `multiplyadd` actually cheats since `*` and `+` are not in CPS. It is very tedious to add all the operators in CPS form, replace all the Lua library functions with CPS equivalents, and translate/generate all your code to CPS; see [details here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation_passing_style).

Comment: Wow, you got me really close to understanding this. Can you expand on the definition for the callcc function? Especially by explaining the part that allows it to remember save/remember all the state like Scheme's call/cc does.

Comment: I guess I'm having trouble how one would use this callcc function - in Scheme you have to set a place for call/cc to jump to, but in CPS you don't... this is throwing me off I think.

Comment: Since k is the closure that callcc will return to, passing it to its argument f accomplishes call/cc's job [I just edited my definition above since I forgot to return properly]. It is trivial when the program is in CPS because the continuation is always available; in Scheme its hidden, and call/cc's job is harder (at the language level, the implementation may be just as trivial in the compiler) since it has to "reify" the continuation.

Comment: Ok, now is that callcc definition of yours equivalent to Scheme's? Meaning, is that the function that captures the continuation so I can invoke it later? I've always thought that the name "callcc" was misleading (at least for the way it's used in Scheme).

Comment: Yes, the callcc is equivalent to Scheme's with the exception that the continuation is as explicit argument (since the program is in CPS) rather than an implicit argument (since Scheme uses direct style).

Comment: is callcc really "return k(f(k))" or is it "return f(k(k))" ? I can't find any references to the former, but I found a few references to the latter: Kalani's comment here: http://blog.lab49.com/archives/893 and the second PDF link ("principles of programming languages") on the google result page that you get when looking for "callcc f k" (with the quotes).

Comment: please substitute the above "or is it return f(k(k)) ?" for this text:
or is it (haskell notation now) "callcc f k = (f k) k" (same as "callcc f k = f k k") ?

Comment: @Pessimist, yes, the function f needs both a continuation and an argument; I was thinking in a hybrid of direct and CPS (probably because I was using non-CPS operators in the multiplyadd example). So it should be "return f(k,k)" -- I've edited my answer. Of course all of this is convention. Any function in CPS can get its continuation from its first argument, so callcc is redundant/unnecessary.

Answer (score 17):

I guess you forgot the part about writing your program in continuation passing
style. Once you do that, call/cc is trivial (in Lua or in any other language),
as the continuation will be an explicit parameter to all functions (call/cc
included).

PS: besides closures, you also need proper tail calls to program in continuation
passing style.

Comment: First of all, it's an honor to have you reply to my question. I am completely in love with your language, for many many reasons (small core, C integration, very consistent grammar, real closures, first class functions, etc).

Now on to the answer: that PS clarifies a lot. Would it be impolite if I asked for an example implementation of call/cc in Lua being that Lua allows for both closures and tail-call optimization? :)

Comment: I agree with Norman Ramsey's reply below. I guess a better question would be, are there any plans of implementing first-class continuations and thus callcc in Lua? ;)

Comment: Good point.  I've edited Wikipedia to clarify on proper tail calls.   The article on "tail recursion" is appalling...

Answer (score 8):

Answering the question about plans for call/cc in Lua: There are no plans for call/cc in Lua. Capturing a continuation is either too expensive or require some code analsis well beyond what the Lua compiler can do. There is also the problem that Lua continuations may include parts in C.

With coroutines, however, we can already implement call/cc1 in Lua (one-shot continuations). That is good enough for many uses of continuations.

Comment: I can understand that. Any plans for a coroutine.clone, then, like the one implemented by Mike Pall on the link in my original post?

Comment: For a working example of callcc in Lua, using a modified Lua that implements coroutine.clone, see this: http://github.com/torus/lua-call-cc/blob/master/callcc.lua . I'll be trying it out shortly. :)

Answer (score 3):

The key phrase is

> It is possible to implement programs in *continuation-passing style*

(Emphasis mine.)   You do this by taking regular "direct-style" programs and converting them to continuation-passing style (CPS) by a program transformation called the *CPS transform*.  The key is that the CPS transform of `call/cc` is a simple function.

**This is not practical for programmers.**  The CPS transform has two uses:

- As a theoretical idea for studying language features, especially control operators
- As a pass in a compiler that uses CPS as an intermediate language

You don't want to go anywhere near doing CPS transforms on Lua code, especially not by hand.

Comment: You might not want to write entire applications using CPS, but it's entirely practical to implement individual algorithms to solve subproblems this way.

Comment: *the CPS transform of call/cc is a simple function* - Careful!  call/cc may be defined in the target of the CPS transformation by a simple function, but it is not the CPS transform of anything since it does not return by calling its continuation.

Comment: The question was 'how' and not 'should'.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible:
TypeScript-to-Lua Compiler https://github.com/roblox-ts/roblox-ts +
call-cc in JS https://github.com/zaoqi/callcc.js/blob/master/callcc.js

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score -2):

Here's my cps-convert in scheme, just pass it every function you want to convert.

```scheme
(define (cps-convert function . functions)
  # Since "help" is called at 2 different places...
  (define (help) (error "syntax: (cps-convert f1 f2 ...)"))
  # Single function converter
  (define (convert func)
    # "name" contains the function's name prefixed with "cps-"
    (let ([name (string->symbol
                          (string-append "cps-" (symbol->string func)))])
      # Dirty hack to define "cps-*" in the global environment
     `(eval '(begin
                   # Necessary to prevent the function from being evaluated
                   (define ,name #f)
                                # Magic
                   (set! ,name (lambda (k . args) (k (func args)))))
                 # Global environment
                 (interaction-environment))))
  # Prerequisite... Call help if condition not met
  (if (symbol? function)
      # function is a symbol
      (cond
        # If there is only one function to convert
        [(null? functions) (convert function)]
        # Else ensure every other "functions" are symbols and convert each
        [(every symbol? functions) (apply convert function functions)]
        # Oops! Condition not met!
        [else (help)])
      # Else clause from previous "if"
      (help)))
```

Comment: This is irrelevant with regards to the question.