# Haskell version of yin-yang puzzle : Kind incompatibility error

Tags: haskell, data-kinds

I want to implement the [yin-yang puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250474/does-the-yin-yang-continuations-puzzle-make-sense-in-a-typed-language) in Haskell. Here is my attempt (unsucceful):

```
-- The data type in use is recursive, so we must have a newtype defined
newtype Cl m = Cl { goOn :: MonadCont m => Cl m -> m (Cl m) }

yinyang :: (MonadIO m, MonadCont m) => m (Cl m)
yinyang = do
    yin <-  (callCC $ \k -> return (Cl k)) >>= (\c -> liftIO (putStr "@") >> goOn c)
    yang <- (callCC $ \k -> return (Cl k)) >>= (\c -> liftIO (putStr "*") >> goOn c)
    goOn yin yang
```

When look at the types, obviously `callCC $ \k -> return (Cl k)` gives a `m (Cl m)`, so `yin` is of type `Cl m`. `yang` is the same thing. So I expect `goOn yin yang` gives the final type `m (Cl m)`.

This implementation looks good, but the problem is it does not compile! here is the error I got:

```
Couldn't match kind `*' against `* -> *'
Kind incompatibility when matching types:
  m0 :: * -> *
  Cl :: (* -> *) -> *
In the first argument of `goOn', namely `yin'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: goOn yin yang
```

Any idea to fix this?

**UPDATE**

Although I found the answer by myself, I still don't understand what that error message means. Can any one explain to me? What I know already is, in the problematic version, `goOn c` returns something like `Cl m -> m (Cl m)`, not the expected `m (Cl m)`. But that is not what you can get from the error message.

Comment: The kind error comes from Haskell trying to use `Cl` as a monad. Monads take a type parameter of kind `*` (a concrete type), while `Cl` takes a parametrized type of kind `* -> *` as a type parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a stupid error in the code. Here is the correct implementation

```
newtype CFix m = CFix { goOn :: CFix m -> m (CFix m) }

yinyang :: (MonadIO m, MonadCont m) => m (CFix m)
yinyang = do
    yin <-  (\c -> liftIO (putStr "@") >> return c) =<< (callCC $ \k -> return (CFix k)) 
    yang <- (\c -> liftIO (putStr "*") >> return c) =<< (callCC $ \k -> return (CFix k)) 
    goOn yin yang
```

It is very easy to run this.

```
main :: IO ()
main = runContT yinyang $ void.return
```

or even

```
main :: IO ()
main = runContT yinyang undefined
```

Although the later looks scary, but it is safe because the continuation will never have the chance to be evaluated. (The overall expression, will be evaluated to value `_|_` because it never stops)

It outputs the expected result

```
@*@**@***...
```

**Explained**

The original attempt is to directly translate the Scheme version

```
(let* (
 (yin
    ((lambda (cc) (display #\@) cc) (call-with-current-continuation (lambda (c) c))))
 (yang
    ((lambda (cc) (display #\*) cc) (call-with-current-continuation (lambda (c) c)))))
(yin yang))
```

into Haskell. For a typed language, the key to make the above type check is to have a type `t` that isomorphic to `t -> t`. In Haskell this is done by using `newtype` keyword. Also, to have side effects we need `IO`, but it does not support `callCC`. To support the later we need `MonadCont`. So to work with both we need `MonadIO` and `MonadCont`. Also, the `newtype` must know which `Monad` it is working on, so it shall carry the `Monad` as its type parameter. So now we write

```
newtype CFix m = ...

yinyang :: (MonadIO m, MonadCont m) => m (CFix m)
```

Since we are wroking on a `Monad` it is convenient to use `do` notation. So `let*` assignments shall be translated to `yin <-` and `yang <-`. In a `MonadIO` to `display` we use `liftIO.putStr`. The `call-with-current-continuation` translate to `callCC` but obviously we cannot translate to `id` or the like. Let's leave this for a moment.

My mistake is naively translate the combination operator of the display block and the `callCC` block to `>>=`. In Scheme or other strict language, the parameter is to be evaluated before the expression, so the `callCC` block shall execute before the display block. As a result, we shall use `=<<` instead of `>>=`. The code is now looks

```
newtype CFix m = ...

yinyang :: (MonadIO m, MonadCont m) => m (CFix m)
yinyang = do
    yin <- (\c -> liftIO (putStr "@") >> return c) =<< (callCC $ ...)
    yang <- (\c -> liftIO (putStr "*") >> return c) =<< (callCC $ ...)
    ...
```

Now it is time to make it type check and see what shall we put in the `...`s. `callCC`s signature is

```
MonadCont m => ((a -> m b) -> m a) -> m a
```

so its parameter have type

```
MonadCont m => (a -> m b) -> m a
```

for some type `a` and `b`. By looking at the code written so far, we easily conclude that `yin` and `yang` shall have the same type of `callCC`s return value `m a`. However, the original schema version uses `yin` and `yang` as functions so they have type `p -> r`. So here is where we need recursive types and `newtype`.

To obtain a `m a` the straight forward method is use `return`, and we need something have type `a`. Let's suppose this is came from the type constructor that we are going to define. Now to supply parameter for `callCC` we need to construct an `a` from `(a -> m b)`. So this is what the constructor would looks like. But what is `b`? An easy choice is to use the same `a`. so we have the definition of `CFix`:

```
newtype CFix m = CFix { goOn :: CFix m -> m (CFix m) }
```

and an implementation of the `callCC`'s parameter

```
\k -> return (CFix k)
```

we use `CFix` constructor to construct a `CFix` from the given parameter, and use `return` to wrap it to the desired type.

Now, how do we use `yin` (of type `m (CFix m)`) as a function? The type destructor `goOn` allow us to extract the inner function, so we have the definition for the last `...`.

```
newtype CFix m = CFix { goOn :: CFix m -> m (CFix m) }

yinyang :: (MonadIO m, MonadCont m) => m (CFix m)
yinyang = do
    yin <-  (\c -> liftIO (putStr "@") >> return c) =<< (callCC $ \k -> return (CFix k)) 
    yang <- (\c -> liftIO (putStr "*") >> return c) =<< (callCC $ \k -> return (CFix k)) 
    goOn yin yang
```

This is final version of the program.

Comment: I have no idea how to follow any of this. So motivating!

Comment: Dang it! You just beat me.. I called mine `CFix` instead of `ContL` though. Ah well now I can get up from my computer

Comment: Good example of why continuations are not compatible with our human brain :)