# Yin-yang puzzle in Ruby

Tags: ruby, scheme, continuations

As an attempt to learn more about `call/cc` in general I saw [How does the yin-yang puzzle work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694679/how-does-the-yin-yang-puzzle-work) question and [this explaination](https://web.archive.org/web/20140129194441/http://yinwang0.wordpress.com/2012/07/27/yin-yang-puzzle) about the yin-yang puzzle:

```lisp
(let*
    (
        (yin (
            (lambda (cc) (display #\@) cc)
            (call/cc (lambda (c) c))
        ))
        (yang (
            (lambda (cc) (display #\*) cc)
            (call/cc (lambda (c) c))
        ))
    )
    (yin yang)
)
```

I probably (or probably not) understood the yin-yang puzzle concept as of by now. But I found that scheme syntax is not particularly easy to understand, and upon searching I found that ruby have [Continuation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Continuation.html) module. Since ruby syntax follows procedural style, I found that it's much easier to read ruby code than scheme code. Therefore I decided to translate the puzzle to ruby version (I'm both novice at scheme and ruby):

```rb
require "continuation"

yin = (lambda do |cc|
    print "@"
    return cc
end).call(callcc {|c| c})

yang = (lambda do |cc|
    print "*"
    return cc
end).call(callcc {|c| c})

yin.call(yang)
```

However this version prints out `@*@***********...` ([demo here](https://tio.run/##jcwxCsMwDEbhOT6F8BR36A0KvYry2xSBI7fCHkLdszsJ3UuXtzz4rC3bGJZeTSyRR9Eq2rhKUe/cJko3mjOvS2SKhTrQ3fQ00Ur@7t1kqTZTAlzSGK7gnOczAL07OuETDob18cO5/O2Ifs8JhjF2)) instead of `@*@**@***@****@*****@**...`, which is not what I expected.

Is my ruby version correct? If it's not correct then I don't really know what's to do from here...

Comment: "_...I found that it's much easier to read ruby code than scheme code._" -- Well, it is much harder to read lisp code when it is formatted in the manner of a curly braces language. Don't scatter parentheses all over different lines; study the formatting of lisp code written idiomatically, and emulate that. Once you get used to the way lisp is typically formatted, it is about as easy and natural to read as any other code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your problem that `yin` and `yang` will become `Continuation` and they don't call together but only `yang` nested inside `yin`.

```rb
yin = (lambda do |cc|
  print "@"
  return cc # (3) return Continuation (1)
end).call(callcc {|c| c}) # (1) this params call first

# (2) lambda will call immediately -> print the first @
# so yin = Continuation (1)

yang = (lambda do |cc|
  print "*"
  return cc # (6) return Continuation (4)
end).call(callcc {|c| c}) # (4) this params call first *

# (5) lambda will call immediately -> print the first *
# so yang = Continuation (4)

yin.call(yang)
```

now we could interpret your code as below

```rb
yin = callcc {|c| c} # yin context
  print '@'
  yang = callcc {|cc| cc} # yang context
    print '*'
    yin.call(yang)
  # end yang context
# end yin context
```

as you can see, after the first time call (the second @ and *) the last line `yin.call(yang)` will keep call yang `yang ( * yang ( * yang ( ...`, if you replace by `yin.call(yin)`, the output will be `@*@*@*@*...`

finally, here is my solution, the idea is that `yin` and `yang` will be nested together, the next `yang` will contains the prev `yin` + '*' and the next `yin` will contains the previous `yang` + '@'

```rb
require "continuation"

yin = lambda { |yang|
  cc = callcc { |cc| cc }
  print "@"
  yang.call(cc)
}
  
yang = lambda { |yin|
  cc = callcc { |cc| cc }
  print "*"
  yin.call(cc)
}

yin.call(yang)
```