# What is suspendCoroutine?

Tags: kotlin, callback, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, suspend

I am a beginner studying `coroutines`.

Not exactly, but I have a little understanding of what a `coroutine` is.

The `suspend function` is also difficult, but with a little understanding.

I'm studying step by step, but there are parts I don't understand.

That's `suspendCoroutine`. In the sample code, `suspendCoroutine` and `Continuation` used in the block appear, but I have no idea what these two are.

I've looked on other sites, but I can't find anywhere that explains it easily.

Can you explain what `suspendCoroutine` and `Continuation` are used for easily and, if possible, with an example?

Comment: I found these slides to be helpful https://www.slideshare.net/elizarov/introduction-to-coroutines-kotlinconf-2017

Comment: Note that continuations and `suspendCoroutine()` are pretty much advanced stuff. They are definitely not the easiest to understand in the whole coroutines machinery.

Comment: Although using `suspendCoroutine` is pretty straightforward, truly understanding how it does the magic it does can be mind-bending. I suggest [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48112934/1103872) as one way to gain that insight.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`suspendCoroutine` is a builder function that mainly used to convert callbacks into `suspend` functions. Let's say for example you have some legacy (or not) Api, that uses callbacks. You can easily transform it into a `suspend` function to call it in a coroutine. For example:

```
suspend fun getUser(id: String): User  = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
      Api.getUser(id) { user ->
          continuation.resume(user)
      }
}
```

Here we have an Api function `getUser`, which defined in `Api` class for example like this:

```
fun getUser(id: String, callback: (User) -> Unit) {...}
```

`suspendCoroutine` suspends coroutine in which it executed until we decide to continue by calling appropriate methods - `Continuation.resume...`.
`suspendCoroutine` mainly used when we have some legacy code with callbacks.

Using `suspendCoroutine` to convert callbacks into `suspend` functions makes the code sequential when you work with `suspend` functions.

For example instead of having a callback hell like this:

```
Api.getUser(id) { user ->
      Api.getProfile(user) { profile ->
          Api.downloadImage(profile.imageId) { image ->
              // ...
          }
      } 
}
```

after you apply `suspendCoroutine` to those callbacks and convert them into `suspend` functions, the code will look like the following:

```
val user = getUser(id)
val profile = getProfile(user)
val image = downloadImage(profile.imageId)
//...
```

Comment: I understand a little bit, but it's still difficult.Let me ask you a question.
`1.` You said you could convert it to a `suspend function` to call from a `coroutine`. Isn't it possible to use regular functions within a `coroutine`? Why use it as a `suspend function`?

Comment: `2.` You said `suspendCortuine` is a builder that converts `callbacks` into `suspend functions`. So, if I put a callback function in the block(`{}`) of `suspendCoroutine` in the first code, does the `callback function` become a `suspend function`?In this case, `Api.getUser` is a callback function, so is it a `suspend function`?`3.` How can the last callback codes be expressed as `suspendCoroutine`?

Comment: 1. The point of coroutines is to run some code in concurrently without blocking the Main Thread. Using `suspend` functions makes your code sequential and asynchronous. You can call not `suspend` functions in a coroutine, but it makes no sense, you can call them without a coroutine.

Comment: 2. No, the original function doesn't become a `suspend` function. Suspend functions are marked with `suspend` keyword, like this: `suspend fun getProfile()`. When you use `suspendCoroutine` you create another function, which becomes `suspend`, see my example: `Api.getUser(...)` is not suspend, but  `suspend fun getUser(...)` is suspend, it is two different function with the same purpose, the last one calls the first one.

Comment: I see.. I will ask the question while checking the OP's code slowly from the beginning.. `A.` In the first code, `suspend fun getUser(id: String)` is not a function created with `suspendCoroutine`. It is just a normal suspend function. Right? and I'm trying to make the `callback API.getUser()` a suspend function using `suspendCoroutine`. Is that right?

Comment: `B.` Is the first code correct for applying `suspendCoroutine` in the `callback hell` code? However, the first code does not appear for the `getProfile()` and `downloadImage()` apis. Should I apply` suspendCoroutine` to each of these two functions as in the first code?

`C.` Is it correct that `getProfile()` and `downloadImage()` with `suspendCoroutine` applied in the last code are also written like the first code?

Comment: I don't understand your questions. There are a lot of docs and tutorials on YouTube about `suspendCoroutine`, for example this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OmHePYcHbyQ

Comment: In the last code, `val user = getUser(id)` is the `suspend fun getUser(id: String): User  = suspendCoroutine { ... }` of the first code, right? If correct, `getUser()` is a `suspend function`, so why use `suspendCoroutine` in return again? Can't we just use it in this format? `suspend fun getUser(id: String): User { return Api.getUser(id) }`

Comment: No, `Api.getUser(id)` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 5):

`suspendCoroutine` is Kotlin's name for [Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(programming_language))'s function [`call-with-current-continuation`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation) (abr. `call/cc`).

It is explained in this video ["Fresh Async With Kotlin • Roman Elizarov • GOTO 2018"](https://youtu.be/hb0hfHVWCS0).

The article ["The Yin-yang puzzle in Kotlin"](https://medium.com/@georgeleung_7777/the-yin-yang-puzzle-in-kotlin-bb1d5449d6f0) explains it based on the [Yin-yang puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2694679/402322), which is a famous example use case for `call/cc`. Other use cases are explained in the article ["Continuations by example: Exceptions, time-traveling search, generators, threads, and coroutines"](https://matt.might.net/articles/programming-with-continuations--exceptions-backtracking-search-threads-generators-coroutines/).