# In Scheme, why would you use let instead of let*?

Tags: scheme

Is it because we want to conserve memory space?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Let in Scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946050/using-let-in-scheme)

Answer (score 3):

Scott's answer is correct, but I want to pitch in with another perspective.

Scheme culture cares a great deal about functional programming. Functional code should not care about ordering of operations. This is, in fact, why an expression like `(foo (bar) (baz (qux)))` does not say anything about which order those functions will be run, except that:

1. `qux` will be run before `baz` is run
2. both `bar` and `baz` will be run before `foo` is run

In particular, `qux` can be run before or after `bar`, and even a sequence like `qux` → `bar` → `baz` → `foo` is valid.

For a similar reason, `let` should be used by default; it signals to the reader that the usual functional assumptions apply, that the bindings can be evaluated in any order. `let*` should only be used to alert the reader to the unusual behaviour of having bindings depend on previous ones in the same `let*` form.

Answer (score 2):

`let*`, at the cost of being more capable, has to serialize the terms being defined (since each can depend on previous ones), whereas the terms in a `let` can be set up in any order (and even in parallel, should the architecture allow for that).